# Reset a list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have a list (id '#staff') which displays the names of staff stored in the database.

The user can open up a editor which allows them to re-order, add and remove content and then save his changes or cancel.

The save function works.

My problem is when you make changes and click the cancel button and then re-open the editor again the changes are still displayed instead of being reset.

I've tried:

```
$('#staff').reset();
```

but this didn't work.

I want to avoid using a page refresh.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you post the HTML for the list?

Comment: Hard to answer this without knowing more information (though an example would prove more helpful). Is `#staff` an input field? an `<ul>`, ...?

Comment: reset is useful for forms only, is it not?

Comment: I hope this didn't scare you off. We want to help with this issue. We just want to make sure you get the most number of people looking at the problem. I hope you will post a follow-up question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the page loads for the first time, make a clone of the list for the future, then replace the list with the copy later.

```
$(function() {
    var my_copy = $('#list').clone(true);
    $('#reset_button').click(function(){
        $('#list').replaceWith(my_copy);
    });
});
```

Documentation:

- [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

To make this more flexible, store the clone in the list itself.

```
$(function() {
    $('#editor_open_button').click(function() {
        $('#list').data('my_clone',$('#list').clone(true));
    });
    $('#reset_button').click(function(){
        $('#list').replaceWith($('#list').data('my_clone'));
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 - That's nice. Short and sweet. jQuery sure makes things easy.

Comment: This only works the first time. It doesn't work if the user opens the editor multiple times, makes changes and then cancels the changes.

Comment: @user2184530 Hi, Joe made an effort helping you and other people with this issue. He did so for free and for no return other than your, and this community's gratitude. Generally follow up questions are usually frowned upon here. If this answer solved your problem and answered your question please consider accepting it. If you have other questions please consider asking them in a new thread instead of adding 'follow up' questions here. Not only are such follow up questions frustrating for the answer giver, they also make it impossible to others with the same problem solve their issue...

Answer (score 0):

You should store the original content in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the state of the controls/data. Then, if the cancel button is clicked, overwrite all the values of the controls with the saved data.