# Keep older value of a dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following html that is rendered by a django. Here is an instance of how it could be

html

```
<div class="treatment container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="treatment-phrase col-md-4">
                <form action="" method="post" class="inline">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="hbdqhZuNYn83WvZg110TCiENekDqWjUD">
                    <p class="text-info" data-id="2">TR - 35</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm edit-phrase">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="treatment-phrase col-md-4">
                <form action="" method="post" class="inline">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="hbdqhZuNYn83WvZg110TCiENekDqWjUD">
                    <p class="text-info" data-id="3">TR - 34</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm edit-phrase">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

The css

```
.panel-body { padding:0px; }
.panel-body table tr td { padding-left: 15px }
.panel-body .table {margin-bottom: 0px; }
.panel-group,
.settings{
    padding-top:2em;

}

.diagnosis-phrase, 
.treatment-phrase,
.category-item{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.diagnosis-phrase input[type="text"],
.treatment-phrase input[type="text"],
.category-item input[type="text"]{
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}

.category-item p{
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom:0.3em;
    border-radius:0.5em;
    width:50%;
}
```

and js

```
$("#save-phrase").on('click', function (event)  {
    form = $("form#add-phrase")
    form.submit();
});

$(".edit-phrase").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var inputBox;
    var form = $(this).parent('form');
    var p = $(this).siblings('p');
    var input = '<input type="text" data-id="'+p.attr('data-id')+'" class="form-control input-sm col-md-4" id="id_phrase" name="phrase" value="'+p.text()+'">';
    console.log(input);

    if($(this).text() === 'Edit'){            
        p.replaceWith(input);
        form.append('<button name="delete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Delete</button>');            
        form.append('<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Save">');
        $(this).text('Cancel');

    }else{
        console.log(p);
        inputBox = $(this).siblings('input#id_phrase');
        console.log(inputBox);
        p.text(inputBox.val());
        inputBox.replaceWith('<p class="text-info" data-id="'+inputBox.attr('data-id')+'">'+inputBox.val()+'</p>');
        $(this).siblings('input[type="submit"]').remove();
        $(this).siblings('button').remove();
        $(this).text('Edit');


    }

});
```

What it does is the following:

It replaces a p dom Element with an input element part of a form and posts the editing the phrase or deleting it (if deleted is pressed) Everything works as it should except for one thing. When user hits cancel it replaces the input box with the previous p. But the way I have written the code the older p is lost so when user cancels the value of p that replaces it is the last value typed when it should be the original one (before editing). How can I save the old value. I can't use one global or two because, the phrases are added dynamically. Note that user could be editing three phrases at the same time (but he can save only one at a time). Do you think that is better if editing is limited to one phrase at a time?That would solve the problem of saving the inital value of the phrase before editing.

Here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/132649) of it.

Comment: See this previous answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237905/reset-a-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got a nice id there, how about a hash table

```
var cache = {};
```

when needing to cache

```
cache[inputBox.attr('data-id')] = p.clone();
```

when you want to retrieve get the old version of the p back grab it from the hash table using the id.

if you want to store multiple versions of a p then use the hash table and have each element be an array implemented as a stack

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've edited a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17237995/1253312) to fit this question:

When the `p` is edited, make a clone of the element for the future, then replace the element with the copy later. By storing the full clone of the `p` in its own `data` attribute, it keeps its own history. You can do multiple "undo" clicks since it will continue to pop its own history from its `data`.

```
$('.edit-phrase').on('click', function() {
    var p = $(this).siblings('p');
    p.data('my_clone', $(p).clone(true));
    // continue with rest of the logic
});
$('.cancel-edit').on('click', function() {
    var p = $(this).siblings('p');
    p.replaceWith($(p).data('my_clone'));
    // continue with rest of the logic
});
```

Documentation:

- [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: I don't have a .cancel-edit button, logic is implemented at the same button, but thank you for answering.

Comment: I'd consider it bad practice to mix presentation with logic (`if($(this).text() === 'Edit')`). The text "Edit" is presentation layer. Use class names to drive your controller.

Comment: So are you suggesting two separate buttons?or just changing the class of the existing one. If the second choice I should use a delegate correct?

Comment: Either choice would work. Imagine if you change the text of your button. Imagine the poor soul who maintains this code in the future.

Comment: Yes..I see your point I think I will correct my code with according to your recomendations